# Dot Net core Logout not working return to HOME page when click on BACK button from browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I  am working on dotnet core project. When I click on the logout link from my header I am calling my LOGOUT Method to remove all the session data and then redirect to Account -> Login  Page.

**But  From  the  browser if I click on the BACK BUTTON** it returns to the page from where I clicked on LOGOUT, For example "HOME PAGE".

Please suggest.

What want wrong?

```
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout">LogOut</a>
</li>
```

In  my startup file

```
services.AddSession(options =>
{
options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
});
```

Here is my  logout Action code.

```
public IActionResult Logout()
{
HttpContext.Session.Clear();
return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}
```

Comment: If you have authentication enabled, uou can place `Authorize` attribute on your `Home` method in your `Controller`. Or you can check if the session exists on your Home page view. If it does not exist, the redirect on your view directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code in the logout Action, instead of HttpContext.Session.Clear();.

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
```

UI application has to handle the redirection logic if the user is not authenticated.